# DB2 triggers or monitoring abilities for physical deletion

Tags: logging, triggers, db2, monitoring

I'm pretty new with IBM DB2, so I need some help on this topic please:

In my internship i'm dealing with an IBM DB2 data base with almost 300 tables and one super complex web based API( i am not an expert). The client asked us to prepare a testing manual in order to verify if there is any physical deletion (with logs proof). This data base has been designed and implemented by another third party company and we don't know exactly how they have done it. I have already tested logical deletion with an automated script and it works quite fine. But this second task really trapped me and have no idea how it should be done. My question is, do you know any trigger/monitoring techniques

Any suggestion would be appriciated.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?

Comment: select count(*) from table / delete with api / select count(*) from table.  Simple stuff get busy intern.   Counts must match.

Comment: If you want audit, use the built-in [audit facility](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005483.html)

Comment: Thanks danny117 for your answer. Unfortunately It's not simple as that. Actually i need to implement a trigger or a monitoring mechanism (IBM event monitoring for exp) for a period of time (any period). Also, it should be capable to alert us once a physical deletion apprears and collect the logs into a file or table for further auditing aspects. For additional Infos, we are using IBM DB2 Enterprise Server Edition 9.7 installed on a RedHat. –

Comment: The main task is to provide a method ( trigger, event monitoring or any other existence technics) to monitor and log if a physical deletion happens. Any idea on that? Thanks mates